# Emacs syntax highlighing for PL/M

Tags: emacs, major-mode

I'm about to start a new consultancy gig where I will end up dipping my
toes into some PL/M. I have tried to locate a major-mode for PL/M but have so
far been unsuccessful.

Anyone here that can point me towards a PL/M mode for emacs?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a link [here](http://www.kednos.com/kednos/Resources/Editors) to a PL/I mode for emacs.  It should be 
close enough for PL/M.

Comment: Thanks! will put this into emacswiki for further reference